# Why can I not find the smallest number like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def small(n):
    smallest=n
    for var in range(1,n+1):
        if (smallest > var):
            smallest = var
        else:
            smallest = n
print (small(5))
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but there's no `return` in that function.

Comment: Very strange, even if it worked, the answer would always be 1 unless 0 was passed in.

Comment: It's a builtin: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min

Comment: he mentioned that he have to implement this function on his own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

The first is a coding error, where you don't return anything. You probably want to put `return smallest` at the end of the function.

The second is a logic error. Your `else` block incorrectly sets `smallest` back to `n` any time the latest number considered isn't smaller than the previous smallest value.

Now, even if you fix those, the function is going to be fairly pointless, since the smallest number between 1 and `n` is always going to be 1. However, you could generalize your code to an arbitrary sequence pretty easily:

```
def small(seq):
    it = iter(seq)         # make an iterator
    smallest = next(it)    # initialize smallest to the first item
    for val in it:         # loop over the rest of the values
        if val < smallest: # no else clause needed
            smallest = val
    return smallest        # and don't foget to return a value at the end!
```

This will also work for non-integer values, like strings (which will be sorted lexicographically). However, you should probably just use the builtin `min` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Next try:

## **smallest number in a set of numbers**

```
def small(*n):
    s=None
    for m in n:
        if s is None or m<s: s=m
    return s
```

The `*n` is a "link" to the arguments of `small` (on [asteriks](http://www.technovelty.org/python/on-asterisks-in-python.html)).

It searches for the smallest number in `n` and you can call it i.e.

`small(5,7,19,3,6)` and it will return `3` as it is the smallest number in the set.

as  Blckknght said it's the same like calling `min`, a built-in function. His and mine do the same, you learn a bit about [iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) in his example, that is a pointer to a element in the list of numbers.

---

I have two ideas to implement your function... (first: shorter)

```
def small(n):
     s=n
     for v in range(1,n+1):
             s=s if s>v else n
     return s
```

The usefulness is questionable as it can be implemented this way (second: what it really does):

```
small=lambda x: x
```

As you can see your function does actually nothing useful. Or it does its function, it returns the smallest number of the set [number]. Don't know what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: In a beginner course and we lose points for using any built in functions....So it's like being forced to over-complicate the code. Very frustrating. Thanks for the help!